# Translate month in Symfony 2 date field

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working on SF2 2.6.4 project.
I created a form and added a date type component (birthday field type to be precise).

I set it like that :

```
'widget'    => 'choice',
'format'    => 'ddMMMMyyyy',
```

Format output

```
18 March 2015
```

I would like to translate month.

During my research, I saw that `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType` class set a formatter with the hardcoded `\Locale::getDefault()` variable system.

So is there a way to do what I want ?
Is it a better idea to change my date format ?

Thx

Comment: I don't get what you mean when you say "localise month." Localisation occurs on the entire DateType, not just one part of it. Do you need language translation?

Comment: Yes it was the wrong term. What I want it's translate March (en) to Mars (fr) for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally if you have your intl enabled in php (phpinfo) the form translate the months according to your locale configuration try setting locale like this before your form creation  :

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR");
```

Another alternative if this doesn't help is this :

http://sonata-project.org/bundles/intl/master/doc/reference/datetime.html you can use the datetime helper

Comment: Yes, I didn't have php-intl package installed on my debian. Thx

Comment: This may also the reason for this issue when using Mac OSX.